# Inserting rows in sql table problem, some columns inserted NULL value

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have 2 DB with multiple tables. All tables have the same syntax. Here I have a method that takes name of the table as an argument. The table that I try to insert is with 3 columns (int, varchar, int). The problem is, only the first row is inserted, and the 2 and 3 row is NULL, I don't know what is the problem. Any suggestions, please?

```
public void getAndInsertData(String nameOfTable) {

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB1, user1, password1);
        Statement s1 = con1.createStatement();

        Connection con2 = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB2, user2, password2);
        Statement s2 = con2.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs1 = s1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + nameOfTable);

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd1 = rs1.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd1.getColumnCount();

        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {

            String columnName = rsmd1.getColumnName(column);
            int columnType = rsmd1.getColumnType(column);

            while (rs1.next()) {

                switch (columnType) {

                    case Types.INTEGER:
                    case Types.SMALLINT:
                    case Types.BIGINT:
                    case Types.TINYINT:

                        int integerValue = rs1.getInt(column);
                        
                        String integerQuery = "insert into " + nameOfTable + " (" + columnName + ") VALUES("
                                + integerValue + ");";
                        s2.executeUpdate(integerQuery);

                        break;

                    case Types.VARCHAR:
                    case Types.NVARCHAR:
                    case Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
                    case Types.LONGVARCHAR:

                        String varcharValue = rs1.getString(column);
                        
                        String varcharQuery = "insert into " + nameOfTable + " (" + columnName + ") VALUES("
                                + varcharValue + ");";
                        s2.executeUpdate(varcharQuery);

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Default");
                        break;

                }

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't explicitly put values into a column, then the default value is used.  If no default is specified, then the value is `NULL`.

Comment: Your loops are inside out. The `while` should enclose the `for`.

Comment: I put the for loop below the while, but again didn't work, do you have in code any suggestion? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

- Use try-with-resources to make sure the JDBC resources are cleaned up correctly.
- No need for a `switch` statement, because we don't actually need to know the types of the columns. The JDBC driver will handle that if you use `getObject()` and `setObject()`.
- Only execute one `INSERT` per row from the source table.
- Use *batching* when inserting a lot of records, for better performance.

Here is how to do it:

```java
try (
    Connection conSource = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB1, user1, password1);
    Connection conTarget = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB2, user2, password2);
    Statement stmtSource = conSource.createStatement();
    ResultSet rsSource = stmtSource.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + nameOfTable);
) {
    // Build insert statement
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rsSource.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO " + nameOfTable + " (");
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        if (column != 1)
            sql.append(", ");
        sql.append(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }
    sql.append(") VALUES (");
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        if (column != 1)
            sql.append(", ");
        sql.append("?");
    }
    sql.append(")");
    
    // Copy data
    conTarget.setAutoCommit(false);
    try (PreparedStatement stmtTarget = conTarget.prepareStatement(sql.toString())) {
        int batchSize = 0;
        while (rsSource.next()) {
            for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
                // Copy row here. Use switch statement to control the mapping
                // if source and target table columns don't have compatible types.
                // The following statement should work for most types, so switch
                // statement only needs to cover the exceptions.
                stmtTarget.setObject(column, rsSource.getObject(column), metaData.getColumnType(column));
            }
            stmtTarget.addBatch();
            if (++batchSize == 1000) { // Flush every 1000 rows to prevent memory overflow
                stmtTarget.executeBatch();
                batchSize = 0;
            }
        }
        if (batchSize != 0)
            stmtTarget.executeBatch();
    }
    conTarget.commit();
}
```

Comment: This will be for transfer tables content from Hana DB to one MySQL DB, both use JDBC, the thing is, I understand that exist some differences for some data types, that why I try with switch

Comment: @RobertVasile Hana DB would require a different JDBC driver to that of MySQL, no? You should [edit] your question and add that information, i.e. that the target database is Hana DB and the source database is MySQL.

Comment: @Abra It's the other way, *from* Hana *to* MySQL. --- Anyway, since we don't know the content of `urlDB1` and `urlDB2`, ***we*** shouldn't assume that they are the same database flavor, i.e. use the same JDBC driver.

Comment: I don't know yet, my mentor told, we have 2 DB, one is Hana DB and one is MySql, both using JDBC, and he needs something to transfer the table content from Hana to MySql. He suggested that switch because he says that can be some different data, for example, some data can be stored into String fields for example, for not losing data when he transfer, because of precision, length etc.

Answer (score 3):

Your `integerQuery` and `varcharQuery` both insert into datebase table a record with one filled column and blank other columns. Because you provide value to one column only.

Comment: I saw that, but I can't understand how to put all values, any suggestion?

Comment: Use StringBuilder to form a list of column names and a list of values.

Comment: I did a list of column names, but I don't know how to make a list of values there, because I need to take all columns in that filter...

Answer (score 1):

As The Impaler already mentioned, your loops are at the wrong place.
For every record of rs1, you want to insert one record using s2.

You can build a prepared statement first using the metadata and then inject the values:
ResultSetMetaData rsmd1 = rs1.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd1.getColumnCount();

```
StringBuffer sql=new StringBuffer("insert into "+nameOfTable+" (");
for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {

    String columnName = rsmd1.getColumnName(column);
    if(column>1)
        sql.append(",");
    sql.append(columnName);
}
sql.append(") values (");
for(int i=1;i<=columnCount;i++)
{
    sql.append((i==1?"":",")+ "?");
}
sql.append(")");
System.out.println("Prepared SQL:"+sql.toString());
// sql = insert into nameOfTable (col1,col2,col3) values (?,?,?)
PreparedStatement s2= con2.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

while (rs1.next()) {
    s2.clearParameters();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {

        int columnType = rsmd1.getColumnType(column);

        switch (columnType) {

            case Types.INTEGER:
            case Types.SMALLINT:
            case Types.BIGINT:
            case Types.TINYINT:
                s2.setInt(column, rs1.getInt(column));
                break;

            case Types.VARCHAR:
            case Types.NVARCHAR:
            case Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
            case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
                s2.setString(column, rs1.getString(column));
                break;
            default:
                System.err.println("Not supported type for column "+column+" with type:"+columnType);
                s2.setNull(column, columnType);
                break;
        }
    } // end of for loop
    // execute statement once per record in rs1
    s2.executeUpdate();
} // end of while
```

Comment: I try and he gives me this exception:  java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).

Comment: You're right, the first for loop's end condition must be `column <= columnCount`. `=` was missing.

Comment: Now I have another exception that say: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'numar' in 'field list'        "numar" is the last column name in the table

Comment: @RobertVasile Seems your target table doesn't have the same columns as the source table. Check the tables to be sure they have the same columns, with the same names and types.

Comment: I've added a System.out.println to print out the prepared statement (not tested, hope it prints some human readable SQL). If you want this code to be more resilient, you should compare the metadatas of both tables to verify they have the same column definitions and throw an exception with the details of the diff(s).